# Is it safe to delete log file in C:\Windows\system32\LogFiles\Httperr

Tags: windows

Files in C:\Windows\system32\LogFiles\Httperr folder growing very big and take a lot of space.

DO anybody know whether it is safe to delete these files?

Comment: This is a reasonable question, and log management is clearly on-topic for serverfault, I don't understand why anyone would vote to throw it away instead of moving it.

Answer (score 7):

They are just logfiles so from a technical perspective you can throw they away (except for the most recent, which will probably in use).

It possible though that because of compliance regulations or company policy you need to retain these for some period of time.

Find out if that is the case and simply move the oldest to other media if needed.

The logging behavior itself can be configured in the property panels of Internet Information Server. You can even switch it of altogether if you don't need the logs or move them to another location so they don't clog up your c: drive.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is safe to delete them, as they are just log files.
But the fact that it's getting large means that it's storing a lot of errors from your IIS server, this is just something to be aware of.

Comment: It may not be safe to delete them if your company has any sort of compliance requirements for retention of activity logs. Also, these can be a valuable source of forensic data in case of any hacking incident or investigation.

Answer (score 0):

Turf the old files, I would keep the most recent (last 1-2 months) but if you're like most, these log files have been accumulating for several months or years depending on the age of the web server, as for the comments on compliance requirements for retention of activity logs, ie. SOX, etc.  These boxes would already be covered by backups in place that are also part of the SOX Compliance requirements - if necessary, you could always restore the log files from previous backups.  I found 2.5GB worth of log files in C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR on an older Windows 2008 web server, and the cleanup performed prevented having to grow the disk.